# C++ [] index operator overloading

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, operator-overloading

#### Base.h

```
#pragma once
class Base {
protected:
    std::string name;

public:
    Base() {
        //something
    }
    Base(std::string name) {
        //something
    }

    std::string getName() {
        return this->name;
    }

    void setName(std::string name) {
        this->name = name;
    }
};
```

#### Derived1

```
#pragma once
#include "Base.h"
class Derived1 : public Base {
protected:
    int other;

public:
    Derived1() {
        //something
    }
    Derived1(int other) {
        //something
    }
};
```

#### Derived2.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Derived1.h"
class Derived2 : public Derived1 {
protected:
    int other;

public:
    Derived2() {
        //something
    }
    Derived2(int other) {
        //something
    }
};
```

#### Derived3.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Derived2.h"
class Derived3 : public Derived2 {
protected:
    int other;

public:
    Derived3() {
        //something
    }
    Derived3(int other) {
        //something
    }
};
```

#### Foo.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "Base.h"
#include "Derived1.h"
#include "Derived2.h"
#include "Derived3.h"

class Foo {
private:
    std::vector<Base*> Vect;

public:
    Foo() {
        //something
    }

template<typename T>
T& operator[](std::string name) {
    bool found = false;
    int index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < Vect.size(); i++) {
        if (Vect[i]->getName() == name) {
            found = true;
            index = i;
        }

        if (found == true) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return Vect[index];
}
};
```

#### Source.cpp

```
Foo foo;
std::string x = "TEXT";
std::cout << foo[x];
```

I have a **class Foo** with a vector of `Base*` **class pointers**.
I'm trying to overload the `[]` (index, subscript) operator for `Foo`, so that I give a string as an input and it returns one element from `Vect` whose private member `name` matches the input.
The element that can be returned can be either of `Derived1`, `Derived2`, `Derived3`, that's why I tried to make it templated.

However, in the source file I get these errors saying

```
no operator "[]" matches these operands
   operand types are: Foo[std::string]
Foo does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Comment: 1) What do you expect `T` to be deduced to, in call `std::cout << foo[x];`? 2) Also, non-void function must return _something_ in all code paths. Your operator doesn't. Hence, in those cases, where it doesn't return anything - it invokes UB.

Comment: What does it returns if `"TEXT"` is not found?  Falling off the end of the routine would be **undefined behavior**.  Should probably `throw` something.

Comment: `getName` -> `getName()`? Although there's not enough information given to know for sure.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I'm sorry I don't get what you mean by point 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator[]` should be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter. Template functions where the template parameter is used as the return type do not work, because the standard invocation of `foo[x]` does not allow the compiler to infer the template type.

To invoke your templated operator, you'd need to do

```
foo.operator[]<Base>(x)
```

which is very verbose.

Remove the template stuff and change the return type of your operator to be a `Base &`.

```
Base& operator[](std::string name)
{
    // ...
    return *Vect[index]
}
```

I've also fixed your return statement.

Note that there are other improvements that can be made to your `operator[]`, and you don't handle the case of the subscript value not being found in your vector (you'll try to reference `Vect[-1]`, which will be undefined behavior).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that I had to remove the template stuff. As per the improvements of the `operator[]`, I know. It was still a WIP, not a final feature, but I really wanted to solve the issues before going further. Thank you